# SQL Server Query to get a number of rows that changed in the past 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am completely new to SQL Server and don't have any idea about it. I tried writing a query similar to oracle and I dont see expected results.

My table has a column whenChanged - sample value is 2011-10-05 21:22:27.0

There are 100k rows in the table and I want the list of rows which got changed in the last 1 day, 1 hour blah.blah.blah.

I wrote a query like select top 10 * from tablename where whenchanged > whenchanged -1.

But dont see what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get all the records that have been changed in the last day:

```
select top 10 * from tablename where whenchanged > DATEADD (D, -1, GETDATE())
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx for the details on the DATEADD function and the other date parts you can specify

EDIT: If you want to get records between 2 dates the something like this will work:

```
select * from tablename where whenchanged BETWEEN 'Date1ValueGoesHere' AND 'Date2ValueGoesHere'
```

Comment: This does not get *all* but only the *top 10*

Comment: How can i change this query to get data between 2 date ranges. date ranges can be passed from properties file?

Answer (score 2):

To get the records changed in the last 24 hours:

```
select * from tablename 
where whenchanged > DateAdd(hour, -24, GETDATE())
```

In the last hour:

```
select * from tablename 
where whenchanged > DateAdd(hour, -1, GETDATE())
```

To get all changed today, you have to tweak a little:

```
select * from tablename 
where whenchanged >= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

The cast eliminates the time part so you'll have `2011-10-05 21:22:27.0` compared to `2011-10-05` which is the same as `2011-10-05 00:00:00.0` in DateTime.

Comment: I don't see them working... First 2 queries returns almost all rows and third one says  Error: Type date is not a defined system type.
SQLState:  S1000
ErrorCode: 243

Comment: Surely it should be GETDATE() being passed as the 3rd parameter to DATEADD and not the whenchanged column

Comment: I imagine the problem with the 3rd query is that the Date date type was only introduced in SQL 2008 and although the OP didn't specify I guess they're using an earlier version

Comment: @Shiv - Do as Paul says. Replace `whenchanged` with `getdate()` in the `dateadd` function. The last query will only work on SQL Server 2008. There is no `date` data type in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Thank You everyone. Sorry that I dont know which version of SQL Server i am using. I used Paul's query and it worked... Thank You Adrian for helping me

Comment: Thank you guys, I was out for a while. It was definitively wrong, `GET_DATE()` was required.

Answer (score 0):

In the last hour:

```
select * from tablename 
where order_date > DateAdd(hour, -1, GETDATE()) and order_date<=GETDATE()
```